# Java String replace Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have a name that can take the following

The allowed characters for description are any alphanumeric character, trademark symbol, registered trademark symbol, dash, underscore, tilda, space and dot.

I want to be able to replace all other characters apart from the allowed with _ (lets say)

Can someone help me out with doing this in java using the String.replaceAll method

Comment: Show us sample input, output.. and more importantly, your *effort*

Comment: Yes, what have you tried so far?

Comment: You've been on the site for more than 4 years, and have asked around 81 questions. I don't mean to sound rude, but I'd expect someone with your reputation to know how to ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
String replaced = yourString.replaceAll("[^\\w\\xAE\\xA9~. -]", "_");
```

- In Java, `\w` matches all ASCII letters, numbers and underscore
- `A9` and `AE` are the hex codes for copyright and registered trademark

Comment: Thank you zx. I was having problems figuring out the copyright and trademark unicodes. This one works for me

Answer (score 1):

```
String rep = str.replaceAll( "[^-_~.\\s\\w\\u2122\\u00AE]", "_" );
```

As for the "registered trademark":  could be another symbol.